# How to activate navigation in jqgrid in asp.net?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

i'm starter in jqgrid, i want active Navigation JQgrid panel  ,But I do not know how to do it

```
<div style="direction: rtl;">
        <table id="list" dir="rtl">
        </table>
        <div id="pager">
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <table id="list1">
        </table>
        <div id="pager1">
        </div>
        <div id="navgrid"></div>
    </div>
```

thanks all.

---

I Write this code, but is n't work

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
                direction: "rtl",
                toppager: false,
              onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    var b = $("#list1 tr").eq(id);
                    alert(b.text());


                },
                recordpos: "left",
                pgtext: "صفحه {0} از {1}",
                datatype: "local",
                colNames: ['کد', 'تاریخ', 'نام', 'مبلغ', 'تلفکس', 'جمع', 'توضیحات'],
                colModel: [
                { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int" },
                { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, sorttype: "date" },
                { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
                { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
            ],
                multiselect: true,
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
                pager: jQuery('#navgrid'),
                sortorder: "desc",
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: "اطلاعات تعرفه ها"
            });

            var mydata = [
        { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
        { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
        { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
        { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
        { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
        { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
        { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
        { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
        { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }
        ];
            for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++)
                jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
            jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('navGrid', "#navgrid", { edit: true, add: true, del: true });


        });
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. The navigator is *the part* of the pager. So if you have the pager `pager` for the grid `list` and the pager `pager1` for the grid `list1` you need just call two times `navGrid` method: `$('#list').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager');` and `$('#list1').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager1');`

Comment: hi @Oleg plese take sample for mr, i'm starter.

Comment: i add this code, but dose't work . jQuery("#navgrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagernav', { }, //options 
            { height: 280, reloadAfterSubmit: false }, // edit options 
            { height: 280, reloadAfterSubmit: false }, // add options
            { reloadAfterSubmit: false });  // del options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be written

```
 $("#list1").navGrid('#navgrid', { refresh: true }, { height: 280, reloadAfterSubmit: false }, { height: 280, reloadAfterSubmit: false }, { reloadAfterSubmit: false });
```

Thanks